# Pandas get the "index" label of a series given an index

Tags: pandas

Ok, so this is confusing because of a lack of vocabulary.

Pandas series have an index and a value: so 'series[0]' contains (index,value).

How do I get the index (in my case it is a date), out of the series by indexing the series?  This is really a very simple idea...it is just encrypted by the word "index."  lol.

So, to rephrase,

I need the date of the first entry in my series and the last entry, when my series is indexed by date.

just to be clear, I have a series indexed by date, so when I print it out, it prints:

```
12-12-2008 1.2
12-13-2008 1.3
...
```

and calling

```
df.ix[0] -> 1.2
```

I need:

```
df.something[0] -> 12-12-2008
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it.

```
 df.index[0]
```

yields the label at index 0.

Comment: df.index[0] does indeed yield the label.

Comment: df.ix[0].name seems to be imaginary code. In some cases .iteritems() might be useful, but not in bordeo's.

Comment: @ThomasB.Higgins ha, thanks for the comment, forgot about this.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the elements of your index just as you would a list. So `df.index[0]` will be the first element of your index and `df.index[-1]` will be the last.

Incidently if a series (or dataframe) has a non-integer index, `df.ix[n]` will return the `n`-th row corresponding to the `n`-th element of your index.

So `df.ix[0]` will return the first row and `df.ix[-1]` will return the last row. So an alternative way of getting the index values would be to use `df.ix[0].name` and `df.ix[-1].name`

Comment: so I don't need the element, I need the "index".

Comment: this is really annoying.  df.ix[0] returns the value at the point df.ix[0].  I need the "index" value at the point df.ix[0]...

Comment: ah..thanks!  it was really difficult to get google to give that one up

Comment: ah that last bit will only work with dataframes. so either go `df=pd.DataFrame(yourseries)` or use the first method